# Common 'out' neighbors and common 'in' neighbors

Tags: networkx

From a directed graph and give two vertices (v, u) I need to find: Common 'out' Neighbors and Common 'in' Neighbors.

E.g:

```
import networkx as nx

ghybrid = nx.DiGraph()
ghybrid.add_edge("A", "B")
ghybrid.add_edge("A", "C")
ghybrid.add_edge("B", "D")
ghybrid.add_edge("D", "C")
ghybrid.add_edge("E", "A")
ghybrid.add_edge("E", "D")
```

[image: Directed Graph]

I want this:

```
# Common out Neighbors
B ,  E :  set(['D'])
E ,  B :  set(['D'])
A ,  D :  set(['C'])
D ,  A :  set(['C'])

# Common in Neighbors
A ,  D :  set(['E'])
D ,  A :  set(['E'])
```

I can have the Common 'out' Neighbors:

```
def common_out_neighbors(g, i, j):
    return set(g.neighbors(i)).intersection(g.neighbors(j))
```

But, I don't know how to get the Common 'in' Neigbors. Can anyone  help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For DiGraphs you can use the `predecessors` and `successors` methods:

```
import networkx as nx

def common_out_neighbors(g, i, j):
    return set(g.successors(i)).intersection(g.successors(j))

def common_in_neighbors(g, i, j):
    return set(g.predecessors(i)).intersection(g.predecessors(j))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    ghybrid = nx.DiGraph()
    ghybrid.add_edge("A", "B")
    ghybrid.add_edge("A", "C")
    ghybrid.add_edge("B", "D")
    ghybrid.add_edge("D", "C")
    ghybrid.add_edge("E", "A")
    ghybrid.add_edge("E", "D")
    print common_out_neighbors(ghybrid, 'A', 'D')
    print common_in_neighbors(ghybrid, 'A', 'D')
# output 
# set(['C'])
# set(['E'])
```